# What should I do when I have found an answer to my XY-problem?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, xy-problem

I have previously posted these two questions:

[Which civlizations are most and least likely to go for religion?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/405964/222252)

[How to quickly find natural wonder?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/405811/222252)

Both of these had the same goal, which is to ensure that I get a prophet before it's too late. Now, I have found an answer that answers Y, but it does not really fit to any of those questions since they ask X. In other words, it's an [XY-problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/374458) Should I just create a new question or what should I do?

Comment: Since both of those questions already have answers, I'd lean towards just posting a new question. It would help to know what your new question would be though.

Comment: @Wipqozn The new question is what I wrote here. It's basically "How do I ensure getting a religion?"

Answer (score 4):

In this instance, I'd just ask a new question. Editing your other questions doesn't make sense in this case, since they already have answers.

For the general case, I'd still lean towards a new question as the default course of action. Worst case is that's its closed as a duplicate of the earlier question, which just helps others find it anyways.

Comment: I don't think it should be a duplicate question. "Which civilizations are likely to go for religion?" and "How do I get a prophet fast?" are two fundamentally different questions, even if the answers may be the same.